# Does enabling @Transactional will keep the ResultSet object open in Spring Boot with Spring Jdbc Template and Oracle database?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions

I am using Spring NamedParamJdbcTemplate in a spring Boot application.
I am defining all the CRUD operations in a different class for reusability and returning ResultSet object as the output for DML operations. When I try to parse the returned ResultSet object in calling class I am getting exception saying ResultSet object is closed. If I parse the Resultset right after I get the reponse from query execution I can do with out any problem but it kills the re usability as I want to use the same method for multiple read operations with different queries.

Adding what I options I know, of this problem to give little bit clarity.

### EDIT:

even it shows the same for configuring different transaction managers for different data sources.
What I have thought was keeping the transaction open on **getStudentInfo(String stdntNbr)** would solve this is( keep ResultSet object open in calling method in different class),but it hasn't worked.

### I have three probable solutions:

1) Parsing the ResultSet object in same method ( or by calling another method in same class) and differentiate the ResultSet object parsing logic based on the query executed and assigning it to proper java bean and send it as an Object type and cast it back in the calling method.

2) Parsing the ResultSet object and assign it to a List of type Map and send the List back to the calling method and there again parsing the List of Map's and assign it to the proper java bean.
This is a performance killer as I am mapping the values twice for the same result( one from ResultSet to List of Map's and another from List of Map's to respective java bean.

3) (Not working)
Enabling Declarative transaction ( if I parse the ResultSet object in same transaction it wont close the ResultSet , so in those terms I am trying to enable the transaction on calling method. But it seems like its not keeping the ResultSet object alive .i.e. ResultSet object is closing as usual when I try to parse. Below is the sample code I am using, at the end please find the stack trace.

## So my questions are:

1) But what I am interested in is to just return the ResultSet object after query execution and parse it on the calling class in another method. Does it possible by using Spring Jdbc?

2) For doing above thing, does enabling Declarative Transaction( @Transactional with the created transaction manager on respective data source) keep the ResultSet object open until that transaction closed(say, calling from a method in Service layer class to a method in DAO layer class) ?

I have referred [**Spring Docs**](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-multiple-tx-mgrs-with-attransactional) to configire

## Note :

I am having two data sources namely **redDataSource, greenDataSource** from them I am creating two NamedParamJdbcTemplate objects namely **redJdbcTemplate** and **greenJdbcTemplate**, for each data source one transaction manager namely **redTxManager** and **greenTxManager**

## Code :

```
@Repository
public class RedJdbcOperations {

   public static final int SQL_TIMEOUT = 5; //in seconds

   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("redJdbcTemplate")
   NamedParameterJdbcTemplate redJdbcTemplate;

   public ResultSet read(String sqlQuery,Map<String,?> paramMap) {
    return redJdbcTemplate.execute(sqlQuery, paramMap, ps -> {
        ps.setQueryTimeout(SQL_TIMEOUT);
        return ps.executeQuery();
    });
}
```

}

when I call the method in above class from the method in below class , I am getting the closed ResultSet object exception.

```
    @Component
    public class StudentDAOImpl implements StudentDAO {

    private static final String STUDENT_DATA_INFO_SQL = "Select STDNT_KEY, STUDENT_TYPE_NBR, GRP_CDE from RED.STUDENT_DATA";

    @Autowired
    RedJdbcOperations redOperations;

    @Autowired
    GreenJdbcOperations greenOperations;

    @Override
    @Transactional("redTxManager")
    public StudentVO getStudentInfo(String stdntNbr) {
        Map<String, ?> mapParam = new HashMap<>();
        mapParam.put("rollNbr", 1444);
        ResultSet rs = redOperations.readCapp(StudentQueries.STUDENT_DATA_INFO_SQL, mapParam);

        try {
            if(rs.next())
               return populateStudentVO(rs);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
           //throw custom exception
        return null;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
           //throw custom exception
        } catch (Exception e) {
           //throw custom exception
        }
        return null;
    }

    private StudentVO populateStudentVO(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        StudentVO student = null;
        if (rs.next()) {
        student = new StudentVO();
        student.setAcctKey(rs.getString("STDNT_KEY"));
        student.setTypeNbr(rs.getString("STUDENT_TYPE_NBR"));
        student.setGrpCode(rs.getInt("GRP_CDE"));
    }
    return student;
}
```

And I have the configuration defined in below class in support of **@Transactional("redTxManager")**

```
  @Configuration
  @EnableTransactionManagement
  @Profile("local")
  public class DBConfigLocal {

        /*varibale configuration for reading from yml files 
        */

      @Bean(name = "redDataSource")
      public DataSource redRestDataSource() {
          return getDataSource(datasourceDriver, redOracleUrl, redDbUsername, redDbPassword, minPoolSize, maxPoolSize,
            maxWaitTime);

      }

      @Bean(name = "greenDataSource")
      @Primary
      public DataSource greenRestDataSource() {
          return getDataSource(datasourceDriver, greenOracleUrl, greenDbUsername, greenDbPassword, minPoolSize, maxPoolSize,
            maxWaitTime);

      }

      @Bean(name = "redJdbcTemplate")
      public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate createRedJdbcTemplate() {

          NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport  daoSupport = new NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport();
          daoSupport.setDataSource(redRestDataSource());
          return daoSupport.getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate();

      }


      @Bean(name = "greenJdbcTemplate")
      public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate createGreenJdbcTemplate() {

         NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport  daoSupport = new NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport();
         daoSupport.setDataSource(greenRestDataSource());
         return daoSupport.getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate();

      }


      @Bean("redTxManager")
      @Primary
      public PlatformTransactionManager redTransactionManager() {
         DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
         transactionManager.setDataSource(redRestDataSource());
         return transactionManager;
      }

      @Bean("greenTxManager")
      public PlatformTransactionManager greenTransactionManager() {
         DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager();
         transactionManager.setDataSource(greenRestDataSource());
         return transactionManager;
      }

      private DataSource getDataSource(String datasourceDriver, String url, String userName, String password,
        int minPoolSize, int maxPoolSize, int maxWaitTime) {
         BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();

         dataSource.setDriverClassName(datasourceDriver);
         dataSource.setUrl(url);
         dataSource.setUsername(userName);
         dataSource.setPassword(password);

         dataSource.setInitialSize(minPoolSize);
         dataSource.setMaxActive(maxPoolSize);
         dataSource.setMaxWait(maxWaitTime);

         return dataSource;
    }
  }
```

Even after configuration I am still getting the **Exception saying ResultSet object is closed**

I am not sure whats going wrong here , any help is appreciated.

### EDIT : stack trace

```
[http-nio-8080-exec-3]: DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet 869 - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing POST request for [/student/v1/recom/query]
[http-nio-8080-exec-3]: DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping 310 - Looking up handler method for path /student/v1/recom/query
[http-nio-8080-exec-3]: DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping 317 - Returning handler method [public com.api.ex.vo.StudentVO com.api.ex.controller.StudentController.studentRecom(com.api.ex.vo.StudentRecmRequestVO)]
[http-nio-8080-exec-3]: DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor 197 - Read [class com.api.ex.vo.StudentRequestVO] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" with [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@7c91e6d4]
[http-nio-8080-exec-3]: ERROR c.a.e.daoimpl.StudentDAOImpl 151 - Error while trying to execute the query = Select STDNT_KEY, STUDENT_TYPE_NBR, GRP_CDE from RED.STUDENT_DATA WHERE STDNT_KEY = :rollNbrjava.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Resultset: next
â€¨ at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:238) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
â€¨ at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.next(DelegatingResultSet.java:207) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
â€¨ at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.next(DelegatingResultSet.java:207) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
â€¨ at com.api.ex.daoimpl.StudentDAOImpl .getStudentInfo(RecomsDAOImpl.java:145) [bin/:na]
â€¨ at com.api.ex.daoimpl.StudentDAOImpl .getStudentInfo(RecomsDAOImpl.java:1) [bin/:na]
â€¨ at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
â€¨ at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
â€¨ at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
â€¨ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
â€¨ at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) [spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) [spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) [spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) [spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy219.getStudentInfo(Unknown Source) [na:na]
â€¨ at com.api.ex.serviceimpl.StudentServiceImpl.getStudentRecommendations(StudentServiceImpl.java:228) [bin/:na]
â€¨ at com.api.ex.controller.StudentsController.studentRecom(StudentController.java:64) [bin/:na]
â€¨ at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
â€¨ at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
â€¨ at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
â€¨ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
â€¨ at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) [spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) [spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
â€¨ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_77]
â€¨ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_77]
â€¨ at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
â€¨ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_77]
```

Comment: Can you please post the entire stack trace?

Comment: @PankajGadge, I am sorry, can't add the full stack trace.

Comment: @PankajGadge oops, this is full stack trace

Comment: The whole point of JdbcTemplate (and NamedParameterJdbcTemplate), is to let you pass callbacks (ResultSetExtractor, RowMapper, or a lower level PreparedStatementCallback to do what you need to and, after the callback has done its job, close the resultset, the statement and the connection. You should not return a ResultSet from your repository. You should return a collection of objects, extracted from the resultset and returned by the callback.

Comment: In short, drop the RedJdbcOperations completely, inject the jdbc templates into your DAOs, and use the Jdbc template drectly from there, preferrably using higher-level methods of the template. another whole point of JdbcTemplate is precisely to handle SQLExceptions properly, instead of ignoring them like you're doing in your DAOs: The template methods open and create connections and statements (and sometimes resultsets), call the callback, and properly deal with SQLExceptions and close the resources.

Comment: Thank you @JB Nizet. I got it. I will use the higher order methods.Actually I am throwing custom exceptions in DAO's after catching the Exceptions. Sorry for that. I have updated the comments under catch block.